# Apache ReWrite all traffic to new base

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I would like to use Apache rewrite to do a 301 redirect for all traffic to the new base url.
I don't want the path to be the same, I want every request to be redirected to just "http://sub.mynewdomain.com".

My .htaccess file looks like that but doesn't do anything:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule . http://sub.mydomain.org/ [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteRule ^(.*) http://sub.domain.org/$1 [R=301,L]

Try the above, this should do what you need to do